# How to access values stored in a dataset in VB?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, dataset

So i have a DB with 3 tables. **User** Table with `U_ID` and `U_Name`, **Class** with `C_ID`, and `C_Name` and **User_Class** Table with `U_ID` and `C_ID`. Foreign keys are set.

I want to display the classes associated with the selected user. The user is identified by their name. I know these are the two SQL statements I need to execute:

```
SELECT U_ID FROM User WHERE U_Name = current_U_name
```

then

```
SELECT C_ID FROM User_Class WHERE U_ID = current_U_ID
```

then

```
SELECT C_Name FROM Class WHERE C_ID = C_IDforAllMatchingRows
```

I wanted to use a dataset to store the results of each statement but I could not figure out how to access one value in the dataset i.e.

`(SELECT C_ID FROM User_Class WHERE U_ID = *dataset.Tables(0).Column(0)*)`  - does not work

I started using gridviews because i could access the values stored in each cell like above.

I must be missing a simple way to retrieve the information i need from these three simple tables.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are ultimately using this based on the user logged in, why not do a join on the three tables if there is some commonality and return the requested fields.

```
SELECT C_NAME 
FROM CLASS AS A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT C_ID
    FROM
    USER_CLASS AS B 
    INNER JOIN
    USER AS C
    ON 
        B.U_ID = C.U_ID
    WHERE 
        U_Name = current_U_name
 ) AS D
 ON 
    A.C_ID = D.C_ID
```

From what I understand of your question it seems like for the student you are trying to return a class list, which this query should do.  If you store it in a data table the your could use linq or a for each and output each row if that is what you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `DataTable.Select()` Method? It is a bit long winded but If all the data is already in the data set you could use something like:

```
    Dim userRows As DataRow() = DataSet.Tables("User").Select(String.Format("WHERE U_Name = '{0}'", Current_User))
    If (userRows.Length = 0) Then
        Throw New Exception("User Not Found")
    End If

    Dim UID As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(userRows(0).Item(0))
    Dim userClassRows As DataRow() = DataSet.Tables("User_Class").Select(String.Format("WHERE U_ID = {0}", UID))

    If (userClassRows.Length = 0) Then
        Throw New Exception("User Not Found")
    End If

    Dim classRows As New List(Of DataRow)
    For i As Int32 = 0 To userClassRows.Length - 1
        classRows.AddRange(DataSet.Tables("Class").Select(String.Format("WHERE C_ID = {0}", classRows(i).Item("C_ID"))))
    Next

    YourGridView.DataSource = classRows
```

*(I primarily use C# so please excuse any errors/faux pas in my VB. Hopefully the logic can still be followed).*

Although Like the earlier answer I would use an SQL approach unless there is a good reason not to retrieve the class last direct from the database for each user:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Class
WHERE   C_ID IN 
        (   SELECT  C_ID 
            FROM    User_Class 
            WHERE   U_ID IN (SELECT U_ID FROM user WHERE U_Name = @CurrentUser)
        )
```

**ADDENDUM**

@Aprillion has raised a good point about joins probably being faster, which is mostly true, I have assumed that C_ID and U_ID are not uniquely contrained in the table User_Class, therefore went for subqueries as this removes the need for `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`, and as such will optimise better. However if U_ID and C_ID are uniquely constrained in User_Class then it could be beneficial to use Joins depending on your RDBMS. SQL-Server will optimise both in almost exactly the same way:

[image: Execution Plan in SQL Server]

In summary the SQL approach is probably beneficial, but the exact SQL you should use will depend on your RDBMS, data structures, indicies and keys.

Answer (score 0):

Like previous answers, i recommend single SQL query to retrieve "the classes associated with the selected user" - but [joins should be faster than subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery):

```
query = "select c.c_name" & _
        " from user u" & _ 
        " join user_class uc on u.u_id = uc.u_id" & _ 
        " join class c on uc.c_id = c.c_id" & _ 
        " where u.u_name = '" & current_U_name & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is:

```
query = "select c.c_name from user u, user_class uc, class c 
  where u.u_name = '" & current_U_name & "'" 
  and u.u_id = uc.u_id and uc.c_id = c.c_id
```